# SQL Server Memory Shrinking

Tags: sql-server-2012, performance, memory

I had a strange issue today on a 3rd party vendor's SQL Server. This is a VM running SQL Server 2012 SP1. The min and max memory settings are set to 9GB. Task manager showed SQL Server was getting the 9GB. SQL Sentry shows over time the buffer pool was getting smaller until eventually we were not able to connect with SSMS. PLE was in the single digits.

The CPU was at 40% for a couple of days prior and I singled it down to Resource Monitor. This appears to be a symptom of the memory issue.

The vendor restarted the service and everything is back to normal.

I found this [KB2845380](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2845380) and think this might be related but I'm not sure. Has anyone run into something like this before? From what I've been told this has happened every month or so.

[image]

Comment: +1 for the pretty picture, but also I would say patch that instance up to SP2 + CU8 (http://sqlserverupdates.com/). This should include the hotfix noted in that KB article.

Comment: Thanks @ShawnMelton that was my gut instinct but being a box that I don't really administer I wasn't sure if I should look elsewhere before recommending an update.

Comment: Oh, I generally recommend an update before I even continue looking at a server...habit. You might look at the `system_health` session and `diag` xel files on the instance, they might show some more information for you.

Comment: Off the top of my head, this sounds to me like memory was removed by the VM manager.  If this is VMWare, look into "balloon driver" for tips.

Comment: @MaxVernon I'm aware of VMWare's balloon driver bur have not seen it kick in before. When the host does borrow some memory does the guest OS still show this memory? For instance I have 16 GB on the guest OS. Balloon driver borrows 1GB. If I look at system properties or task manager will I see 16 or 15?

Comment: You should first apply SP2 and monitor the PLE and memory usage. If you still face the issue come back. Anything abnormal in sql server errorlog ?

Comment: @Shanky Nothing in the SQL Server Error log until the very last moment at which we can't even connect to the database through SSMS. Failed login attempts and insufficient memory errors but nothing leading up to that. The server is not very active in general which explains why services aren't affected until its almost completely out of memory.

Comment: So did insufficient memory error produced dbcc memory dump in errorlog?. If not, can you upload output of `dbcc memorystatus ()` on shared drive and post the link in your question. It seems like you have memory issue. Does sql server account has LPIM and why have you kep min and max server memory to 9 G

Comment: @shanky SQL server not set to LPIM. I didn't configure the box as it was set up by 3rd party software my company purchased before my time. Prior the box had 8GB. They had this issue and doubled it to 16 to see if that helps. It appears it didn't and that's how I got involved. I'm going to bed but I'll run dbcc memorystatus() in the morning.

Comment: @jchao - the balloon driver simply consumes memory within the VM, nothing changes in the configuration of the VM itself.  i.e. memory will still be 16GB.

Comment: Update to this. I've been monitoring the server since the last reboot and the same behavior. The memory is slowly getting smaller. Check vSphere and I don't see the balloon driver being the issue.

Comment: We ran into an issue like this due to a CommVault issue.  CPU would spike and memory would fall off.  The only way to reclaim the memory was to bounce the box.  I don't recall the fix, but it had to do with the CommVault application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up applying the hotfix for KB2845380 and the issue appears to be resolved.